# how to display an array that would depends on what the user wants?

Tags: java, arrays, jcreator

This is 1 method .

```
public static void main(String[] Ropher)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String[] Accommodation = {"", "Standard Room", "Double Room", "Matrimonial Room", "Triple Room"}; // Accommodation
    int SwitchOne, SwitchTwo;
    int Option;//Options

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
     * Costumer's Information
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    do{//Start Of First Loop - Customer's Info
    System.out.print("\nEnter Number Of Records : ");
    int Records = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String [][] Fullname = new String [Records][100];
    int [] Night = new int[100];
    int [] Guest = new int[100];
    int[] Confirm = new int [100];
    for (int x = 0; x < Records; x++){// Start For Records

    System.out.print("\nConfimation Number: ");
    Confirm[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("\nFirst Name: ");
    Fullname[x][0] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    Fullname[x][1] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Guest: ");
    Guest[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("Night: ");
    Night[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println();

    do{// Start Of Second - Main Menu

        System.out.print("\n                             ||Main Menu||\n\n");
        System.out.print("|=====================================================================|");
        System.out.print("\n  ************************     Bed Types     ************************\n");
        System.out.print("|=====================================================================|\n\n");
        System.out.print("1. Standard..............................................P500.00\n");
        System.out.print("2. Double................................................P800.00\n");
        System.out.print("3. Matrimonial...........................................P1,240.00\n");
        System.out.print("4. Triple................................................P1,500.00 \n");
        System.out.print("5. Exit\n");
        System.out.println("\n   (WIfi, air conditioned room, LED TV, FREE BREAKFAST)");
        System.out.println("\t *Except Standard rooms and Double rooms");       

        System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select Room Type: ");
        SwitchOne = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

         //Start of Switch for SwitchOne - First Switch


    if ((x + 1 - Records) == 0){

    System.out.print("\n\nList Of Customers:");

    for (x = 0; x < Records; x++){

        System.out.print("\n|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        System.out.print("\n\nConfirmation Number:      |--------------->  " +   Confirm[x]);
        System.out.print("\nGuest Name:                 |--------------->  " + Fullname [x][0] + " " + Fullname [x][1]);
        System.out.print("\nNumber Of Guest:            |--------------->  " + Guest [x]);
        System.out.print("\nNumber Of Nights:           |--------------->  " + Night[x]);
```

This is just an option, i just don't know what value to put in Accommodation.

***System.out.println("\nAccommodations:                |--------------->  " + Accommodation[SwitchOne]);***

```
            }

    }else{
            continue;
        }

    }// End For Records 

    }while (First);//End Of First Loop - Customer's Info


}//IO
}//Body
```

My program is all about Hotel Information and Billing System.

if there's 2 customer wants to check-in and they pick different rooms, and when i checked the customer's list the output of their rooms are the same.

And i know that the problem is

```
    System.out.println("\nAccommodations:               |--------------->  " + Accommodation[SwitchOne]);
```

what would i do to fixed it ?

Help me with this please.

Comment: please reduce it to the relevant code parts only

Comment: is this enough? @Parker_Halo

Comment: Welcome to SO. People will be more willing to read if you: - Indent your code. - Follow Java conventions and make variables start with lowercase. - Make some more efforts to explain in a way that doesn't require people to make efforts to interpret what you mean (_"call an array"_ ? _"what value to put in Accommodation"_ in order to ... ? _"The problem is if the records are 2 the customer is 2..."_ What does that whole sentence mean ?).
It doesn't matter that with enough effort all the above can be understood. It's your job to minimize the effort required to help you.

Comment: how about this? i specified the problem. @SantiBailors

Answer (score 0):

You are using **SwitchOne** to know the selected accomadation. so if records are 2 or more then the last record will the change the value of **SwitchOne**.

so when you are printing all the details, for all **SwitchOne** will be same.

to avoid that create a new array for selectedAccomadation[] and get it from there.
like this

```
int[] Confirm = new int [100];
String[] selectedAccomadation = new String[100];
...
System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select Room Type: ");
selectedAccomadation[x] = br.readLine();
```

And in for loop get like this

```
System.out.println("\nAccommodations: |---------------> " + selectedAccomadation[x]);
```

please notify me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But the thing is he doesn't know what room to pick because it is not shown yet.

Register ----> Select Room ----> Display

if you have a better idea for this program maybe i can use that .